# Does Task.Factory.StartNew help or hurt in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, task, threadpool

I have an MVC controller action that needs to make several web requests. So in an attempt to free this thread to handle other incoming web requests I wrote something like this:
(**NOTE:** this is an over simplification of the real code)

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{
   MyObj o = await Task.Factory.StartNew<MyObj>(() =>
   {
      WebClient c = new WebClient();
      var res1 = c.DownloadString("...");
      var res2 = c.DownloadString("..."); //Not shown but res1 required for this call.
      return new MyObj(res1, res2);
   }
   return View(o);
}
```

My question is have I made things better or worse by spinning up a new thread to do this work. My intention is to free this .Net thread to handle other incoming requests while the network requests get made. But after looking at it seems to me I'm still making a .Net thread block, just maybe a different one from the thread pool instead of the original, so I'm really no better off. So is my suspicion correct and the above code making things worse?

The benefit of Task.Factory.StartNew() if it worked... is that it simplifies the work inside from having to be done all async. My question though is: Does doing it that way in fact free a thread for handling incoming web requests or is it still tying up the same number of threads from the thread pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are just blocking a different thread now.

If this was good, MVC would just wrap *all* action methods in a new task automatically.

To unblock threads you need async IO somewhere under the covers. The BCL usually provides this. If it says "async" on the box it usually is async IO.

That said, few web apps have the problem of running out of threads. The thread-pool starts tons of threads if necessary. Very few web apps are limited in throughput by the number of threads available. Do you really need to process 100s of concurrent requests? Can your backend services even handle this load? If any of these questions is answered by "no" you don't need async.

Comment: Thank you, it does make sense that you'd need low level building blocks for creating true async methods that would not be using a .net Thread.

Answer (score 2):

The code you made isn't really optimal, since both long operations block each other:

```
var result1 = c.DownloadString("...");
```

will run first and when done, it runs

```
var result2 = c.DownloadString("...");
```

Adding an extra thread where this runs in will not improve performance, nor will it free any open requests.

Comment: It's not shown but they need to run serially because the 2nd web call depends on the results of the 1st. But that's really not the question I am asking.

Comment: If they depend on eachother there is no real need to create an additional thread. This will not help you in any way then.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. The goal isn't parallelization it is increasing the number of concurrent request you can handle.

Comment: Why should creating an additional thread help? The method is already `async`. Two `async` methods in one won't help you.

Comment: My point is your answer is wrong. The downloads do not run in parallel due to the await keyword.

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. Will correct the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to the factory block. You can simplify your example to:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    var result1 = await client.DownloadStringAsync("...");
    var result2 = await client.DownloadStringAsync("...");

    /* whatever you're doing with result1 & result2 */     

   return View();
}
```

Comment: My example is simplified because the real thing is unnecessarily complex to demonstrate the question. The benefit of Task.Factory.StartNew() if it worked... is that it simplifies the work inside from having to be done all async. My question though is if doing it that way does not in fact free a thread for handling web requests or if it still is tying up the same number of threads from the thread pool.